# Elimina los recursos que bloqueen el renderizado en bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

realizando el mantenimiento y mejoramiento de la pagina haciendo de `PageSpeed Insights` me encuentro con el siguiente mensaje.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De los cuales los 3 primeros css son propio y los demás son basados en cdn para realizar lo solicitado por el cliente, ahora como podría corregir este error , debo hacer uso de un plugin o alguna herramienta adicional, cabe recalcar que la pagina esta subida a través del cpanel el cual nos ofrece el servicio de hosting.

De antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Existen diferentes formas de abordar tu problema y creo que todas serían válidas, sin una única respuesta. En la imagen que compartes, en la descripción hay un enlace "Consulta cómo eliminar recursos que bloqueen el renderizado", revisaste allí? Puede ser tu punto de partida.